# Numerically accurate integration of Bessel function with exponentially scaling argument

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, numerical-methods, bessel-functions

I am trying to compute the following integral (numerically, since I couldn't find an analytical expression) for very large $b \gtrapprox 10^9$:

$$
\int_0^1 J_0\left(\exp(b\cdot x)\right)dx
$$

($J_0$ is the Bessel function of first kind.)

The problem is that the argument to the Bessel function quickly overflows and so I have to truncate the integrand to something like (on a 64-bit architecture):

$$
\begin{cases}
J_0\left(\exp(b\cdot x)\right) &, b\cdot x \leq 709.78\\
0 & , \textrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

However at these cutoff values the value of the integral is not stable within desired accuracy ($\Delta \lessapprox 10^{-16}$; especially when using [`scipy.integrate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/integrate.html) the value would be different by a factor of up to $10^2$ between the different methods; the plot was computed with `mpmath`):

[image]

I tried employing [mpmath](http://mpmath.org/doc/current/index.html) for using arbitrary floating point accuracy however when I set the cutoff larger by only a factor of 100 the computation of the integral becomes prohibitively long and only yields an accuracy of $\approx 10^{-12}$.

So does anyone know a way to compute these kind of integrals? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: If we change variables $u = e^{bx}$ then the integral becomes $\frac{1}{b}\int_1^{e^{b}} \frac{J_0(x)}{x}{\rm d}x \approx \frac{1}{b}\int_1^\infty \frac{J_0(x)}{x}{\rm d}x \approx \frac{0.2370}{b}$ (where the constant is $\frac{1}{8} \, _2F_3\left(1,1;2,2,2;-\frac{1}{4}\right)-\gamma +\log (2)$)